# How to get a windowed dataset in tensorflow 2 from an array of numpy arrays?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

Imagine I have some data:

```
some_data = np.array([[1,2,3,4], [5, 6, 7,8]])
```

It looks like this:

```
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8]])
```

Each row represents a different observation, so they should not be combined. I want to create a windowed dataset, each window of size 3, shifted by 1. When I pass a single observation, I get what I want, like this:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(some_data[0])
dataset = dataset.window(size=3, shift=1, drop_remainder=True)
dataset = dataset.flat_map(lambda window: window.batch(3))
```

The result:

```
for x in dataset:
    print(x.numpy())

[1 2 3]
[2 3 4]
```

But when I pass the whole numpy array of arrays, I don't get back anything.

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(some_data)
dataset = dataset.window(size=3, shift=1, drop_remainder=True)
dataset = dataset.flat_map(lambda window: window.batch(3))
```

This is what I would expect:

```
for x in dataset:
    print(x.numpy())

[1 2 3]
[2 3 4]
[5 6 7]
[6 7 8]
```

I guess I could loop over `some_data` and pass one array at a time, and then concatenate the datasets, but this seems like a bad solution. What's the right way to do it?

I'm using Tensorflow 2.0. Thanks!

Comment: What's output do you expect?

Comment: I updated the question with the expected output. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each row of dataset has only one element when you use `dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(some_data[0])`.

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(some_data[0])
for x in dataset:
    print(x.numpy())
1
2
3
4
```

But each row of dataset has four elements when you use `dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(some_data)`.

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(some_data)
for x in dataset:
    print(x.numpy())
[1 2 3 4]
[5 6 7 8]
```

So what you need to do is convert each row and merge it.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

some_data = np.array([[1,2,3,4], [5, 6, 7,8]])
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(some_data)

def parse_samples(x):
    return tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x)\
        .window(size=3, shift=1, drop_remainder=True)\
        .flat_map(lambda window: window.batch(3))

dataset = dataset.flat_map(parse_samples)

for x in dataset:
    print(x.numpy())

[1 2 3]
[2 3 4]
[5 6 7]
[6 7 8]
```